# Django model, how to create varying choices in model field based on form submitted?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Suppose I have a model for books, and a page that user can submit a form to filter books. After a user submit a form, display a result page that has a checkbox for each book, and then user can select some books(at least 1) from the result page and submit a new form.

My question is since the result page depends on the first form submitted, how can I dynamically create a varying choices on the result page?

Comment: this can be easily achieved by multiple ways .. 1) Filtering itself can be achieved in the client side by one of the Javascript frameworks (jquery or angular) or javascript itself. So you do not need to submit the form. 2) If you want the server to handle the filtering, then render a html with filter options and send the result back to the client using ajax json format.  Are you using django forms ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using django form in the result page